# What can be said about this family of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$$\sqrt{a^2+x^2+\left(y-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2}-\sqrt{a^2+x^2+\left(y+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{k} \space\space\space\space n \in \mathbb{Z}, \space\space a,b,k > 0$$ This has popped up in finding the locations of destructive interference on a screen for two spherical waves. $a,b,$ and $k$ are fixed, real constants, and $n$ depicts a specific member of the family. Additionally, $y$ is a function of $x$. Is there a convenient way to simplify the above expression to better show the behavior of these curves? The obvious route is to square both sides, isolate the remaining square root, and square again to eliminate all square roots, but I think this distorts a simpler, more enlightening route. Also, note that $a >> b$ can be used if needed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, my original post was not entirely clear. I have edited it to address your questions. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation can be solved for $y(x)$

Note that the solution has to be checked (by bringing it back into the original equation) in order to reject the parasitic solutions due to the squarings.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, so it is a family of hyperbolas. Rewriting your results gets $\frac{4y^2}{C^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2-C^2}=1+\frac{4a^2}{b^2-C^2}$. I plotted the first 22 of these, which gets a very cool graph that I uploaded [here](http://imgur.com/Pi87brG). Thanks!

Comment: There should be a $4$ in front of my $x^2$ term.